# SWFUpload and Uploadify upload file very fast but error in certain computer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, uploadify, swfupload

It is very weird that only several computer has this error, this error happens to both Uploadify and SWFUpload that is trying to upload file to ASP.NET MVC action.

When upload, the percentage jumps very fast and suddenly 100% though the file is very large, and it then hangs at 100% and showing uploading for a long time before then showing IO Error.

I think this is ASP.NET problems not the flash component, any one knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue, it is because anti virus is active and the 100% jump is happening with PC with AVG anti virus, which the software force the file to be uploaded to the anti virus locally thats why it explain sudden jump to 100% and then the anti virus will upload the file to the server in the background.